# Access an SWT button from another method

Tags: java, button, user-interface, swt

I am building a GUI and want to access an SWT button that is initialized in the constructor from another method. is that possible?

```
public class MaskeSection {
 final org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Group PRBS_EXT;
     Button PRBS;
 public MaskeSection(Group Part1){

     PRBS_EXT = new org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Group(Part1, SWT.NONE);


             final org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button PRBS = new org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button(PRBS_EXT, SWT.RADIO);
     PRBS.setEnabled(false);
     }

 public void setPRBS(){
             PRBS.setSelection(true);
 }
```

When I want to call the setPRBS(), it gives me Null Pointer Exception because PRBS = Null I suppose, but PBS is already assigned in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining a local variable with the same name as the field in your constructor. So you're basically [shadowing the field variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) which remains uninitialized.

This is how you can solve it:

```
public class MaskeSection {
    private Group myGroup;
    private Button myButton;

    public MaskeSection(Group part) {
        myGroup = new Group(part, SWT.NONE);
        myButton = new Button(myGroup, SWT.RADIO);
        myButton.setEnabled(false);
    }

    public void setPRBS(boolean selected) {
        myButton.setSelection(selected);
    }
}
```

You should really read up on your Java basics. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) is a tutorial about member variables (fields).

Also please stick to the [Java naming conventions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html).